# TextView permitindo apenas numeros

Tags: android, eclipse, textview

Eu quero que minha `TextView` só aceite como entrada números, porém a linha `android:numeric="decimal"` não faz efeito, ela ainda permite que eu digite letras.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para permitir apenas números você deve setar  dentro do seu `EditText`desta maneira :

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Outra maneira seria :

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/myNumber"
 android:digits="0123456789." 
 android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
```

Comment: Não deu certo também

Comment: Como está seu xml? @DaniloAlbergardi

Comment: <TextView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Digite o Segundo numero" 
        android:inputType="number" />

Comment: Isso está dentro de um editText ?@DaniloAlbergardi

Comment: kkkk puts me desculpa, tava colocando na text, era na Edit, Obrigado!

Comment: se a resposta foi satisfatória, marque como certa para ajudar outros usuarios. @DaniloAlbergardi